# I want that my game could be played directly in Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have text-based game and I want that it could be played in Facebook directly. I think I am able to implement it, but where to start? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the PHP SDK here to get started.  It comes with an example app.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

You should also read up on the API docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an API that uses json. You should probably prototype your game as a website first, then hook it into facebook when you're happy with how it works.

Then just hook it into the Graph API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/